# redirect stdout and stderr to a single file with prefixes

Tags: bash, stdout, redirect, stderr

I am writing a bash script and need to redirect the `stdout` and `stderr` output of a command i run to a single file, prefixing each line with `stderr` or `stdout`, accordingly.

is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[annotate-output](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=annotate-output&sektion=1), from [Debian](http://www.debian.org/)'s [devscripts](http://packages.debian.org/sid/devscripts), does this.

The example in its man page:

```
$ annotate-output make
21:41:21 I: Started make
21:41:21 O: gcc -Wall program.c
21:43:18 E: program.c: Couldn't compile, and took me ages to find out
21:43:19 E: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
21:43:19 E: make: *** [all] Error 1
21:43:19 I: Finished with exitcode 2
```

Comment: chose this answer because it is better at preserving order, although you have to be flushing the output all the time...

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
(myCommand | sed s/^/stdout:/ >> myLogfile) 2>&1 | sed s/^/stderr:/ >> myLogFile
```

The first pipe inserts a `stdout:` prefix to the standard output of `myCommand` and appends it to `myLogFile`.

The parenthesis are used to make a single command of all of that. They tell that further redirections apply to what is inside parenthesis and not to `sed` only.

Then standard error is redirected to standard output with `2>&1` (remember that original standard output has already been redirected to a `myLogFile`). Second pipe inserts a `stderr:` prefix to it and appends it to `myLogFile`.

Comment: I was groping my way towards this, but yours is much cleaner.

Comment: can you elaborate on that answer? i think i understand it, except for the parentheses...

Comment: For convenience, `2>&1 |` can be written as `|&` in Bash 4 or zsh.  It's somewhat symmetric to `&>file` or `>&file` which are shortcuts for `>file 2>&1`.

Comment: unfortunately this approach does not preserve order... :(