# How to capture both success and error messages for linux "find" command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

I'm trying to run an auto-delete script to free up space on a remote server.
The command I'm thinking to use is:
`find . -atime +30 -mtime +30 -type f -delete`

What I want is to also capture which files were successfully deleted and which failed because of access issue. How should I do this?  I think this command below might take care of the failures only, but I'm not sure.
`find . -atime +30 -mtime +30 -type f -delete 2>failed_deletions.txt`

Comment: Related: [redirect stdout and stderr to a single file with prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2432535/45249)

Comment: Would advise you to please research a bit before posting because there are numerous questions/answers/discussions on the same topic. Anyway, have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/capture-stdout-and-stderr-into-different-variables). Also, you can have a look at `exe`c & `trap` combinations to capture script executions.

Comment: If you want a log of failed an successful deletions, I would write a program that does its own iteration, file-stating, and file deletion using system calls directly, rather than forcing `find` and `rm` to do something they weren't designed to do. (There is a difference between *feedback* and *auditing*.)

Comment: Your approach deletes the files, but keeps the directory structure untouched. Is this intentional?

Comment: @user1934428 yes it is intentional, and `-type f` option was passed to `find` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` out of the box does not print the files it processes. If you want to list the files, add a `-print` or `-ls` before the `-delete`.

This obviously prints all the files it processes, including the ones it fails to delete for whatever reason.

Redirecting standard output to a different file should be trivial to discover; `command >stdout 2>stderr`

The final command would become

```
find . -atime +30 -mtime +30 -type f \
    -print -delete >success.txt 2>errors.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Less performant, but should do what you wanted:

```
find . -atime +30 -mtime +30 -type f -exec rm -v {} \; >successful.txt 2>failed.txt
```